# Command to apply config changes and restart K8 pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, configmap

I'm trying to figure out if there is a single command that can be called to restart a K8 deployment that would include changes in the config files and at the same time it would pull the new version of a `latest` image AND it would do this via a rolling update.

My exact use case is that we're using the `latest` version of a specific Docker image and I need to write a script that would restart the deployment and trigger it to pull the new version if available. I figured out this can be achieved with `imagePullPolicy: Always` +  `kubectl rollout restart deployment/<deployment-name>`, but I need this script to be able to include the changes from `deployment.yaml` and `configmap.yaml` as well.

I know that I can do this:

```bash
kubectl apply -f -Rf /some/directory
kubectl rollout restart deployment/<deployment-name>
```

However, if I understand things correctly, in some cases this would unnecessarily restart the deployment twice, specifically in situations where there's only changes in the config files, but no new image is available.

Is there a way to achieve this while still using rolling updates? I know that otherwise I could just delete the deployment and create it again.

Comment: If you are willing to helmify your manifests, `helm` offer rolling out only on config changes with some tricks. https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments

Comment: If you can avoid using a `latest` tag then you don't need the manual restart step: changing a Deployment's `image:` will cause all of the Pods to be recreated but only if the value has changes.  It also has a better guarantee that every node will have the same version of the image and makes it much easier to roll back.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to restart all pods when `configMap` object it updated rather than using script I would use [reloader](https://github.com/stakater/Reloader) operator for that.

Regarding image update if you are not able to use specific tag on image your strategy with `imagePullPolicy: Always` + `kubectl rollout restart deployment/<deployment-name>` should do the work.